# Block the password conformation pop-up window for security concern

Tags: javascript, users

In one of our application we need to block the *password conformation pop-up window* for security concern .

Example: When a user creates a new account that time user provides password and in *Firefox* the confirmation window came to store it in cookies or not. We need to block this programatically instead of manually.

I have searched more and more from last two days for disabling `autocomplete=off` feature for my specified forms like *login forms*. I have tried all things that I searched from google but popup is still enable.

1. I added this to all forms in `hook_form_alter`

   $form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
2. I added this to all forms fields that I want to autocomplete off in `hook_form_alter`

   $form['MY_Field_Name']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
3. I added this to all forms fields using jquery

   $("input#Password").attr("autocomplete","off");

But it is still appearing *remember password popup*.

**My Firefox Borwser Version is 40.0.3**

**My Google Chrome Version is Version 44.0.2403.157 m**

Comment: Its not drupal question, cuz its not related to drupal directly.

Comment: Try to look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25433449/5169597

Comment: how you can say that it is not a drupal question my web application is also in drupal 7.x  and i want to know that how to off autocomplete in drupal form alter hook... bcoz above alteration in hook is not working..

Comment: My button is not button type it's submit type so click event is not fired in drupal

Comment: As described in link above - firefox ignores autocomplete. So its not drupal problem. Try this https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but your idea is working if i submit form by javascript or jquery.